# Implementing Ease Effect for VR Rig Rotation

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, oculus

I am currently rotating VR Rig based on the Oculus Controller's Rotation, want to add an effect which does the ease in when controller is Rotated.

Currently based on the below code it looks like VR Camera is attached to Controller and Rotating, rather i want to improve it to look like camera is smoothly following the controller.
Code (CSharp):

```
var ControllerPosition;
var rotationDelta = Quaternion.Inverse(controllerPreviousRotation) * currentRotation;

float angle = rotationdelta.eulerAngles.y;

transform.RotateAround(
                        ControllerPosition,
                         Vector3.up,
                         angle);
```

Tried Lerp, Since the difference between controller's previous and current rotation is very small, the effect isn't visible. Any Help will be helpful.

Comment: what do you mean by 'does the erase'?

Comment: @zambari , "does the ease" like a trail following an arrow, not "erase".

Comment: sorry, my bad. Have you tried transform.rotation=Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, controllerTransform.rotation, Time.deltaTime) ?

Comment: @zambari , Yes it does the ease effect but doesn't stop where my controller stops and it doesn't check for the direction whether my controller is rotating left or right.

Comment: it should effectively stop after a while, and follow the rotation of the controller, easing  is opposite to 'reacting immediately'